# implementation in cometD

Tags: java, comet, cometd

I am new to CometD, Is there any simple example to implement service channel model in case of response/request model. I have seen cometd.org but there is no such example to how to send the response back if i publish to any channel.

This is the client side

```
alert("channel published1");
    dojox.cometd.publish('/service/getlist');   
    alert("channel published");
    dojox.cometd.subscribe('/service/getlist', function(message) {
        alert(message);
    });
```

this is server side "ConfigurationServlet"

```
bayeux.createIfAbsent("/service/getlist", new ConfigurableServerChannel.Initializer() {

        //new EchoService(bayeux);
        @Override
        public void configureChannel(ConfigurableServerChannel channel) {
            /*channel.setPersistent(true);
            GetListChannelListener channelListner = new GetOrderListChannelListener();
            channel.addListener(channelListner);*/
            new EchoService(bayeux);
        }
    });
```

EchoService

```
public class EchoService extends AbstractService{
public EchoService(BayeuxServer bayeuxServer)                                 
{
    super(bayeuxServer, "getlist");                                              
    addService("/service/getlist", "processEcho");                                       
}

public void processEcho(ServerSession remote,Map<String, Object> data)
{       
    try{
    System.out.println("Start Process Echo");
    getBayeux().getChannel("/service/getlist").publish(getServerSession(), "Hello", null);
    System.out.println("End Process Echo");
    }catch(Exception exp){
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
    //remote.deliver(getServerSession(), "/service/getlist", data, null);                  
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On http://cometd.org there is everything you need.

In order to build a very simple example (web application with Javascript client) you need to read in particular:

- [This](http://cometd.org/documentation/2.x/cometd-javascript) for the client side
- [This](http://cometd.org/documentation/2.x/cometd-java/server/configuration) for the server side (configuration)
- [This](http://cometd.org/documentation/2.x/cometd-java/server/services) for the server side (code). From this menu you may want to start with using the first and third bullet points: Inherited Services for the code that echoes the inputed message, and Server Services Integration for the setup of the Bayeux Server through a configuration servlet.

In the pages that I have linked there is all the code necessary, just copy and paste it. In case, come back with more specific questions.

---

EDITED

After looking at your code, I see that for the service configuration you need to copy the code for ConfigurationServlet class from [here](http://cometd.org/documentation/2.x/cometd-java/server/services/integration) and for the EchoService class you need to modify the processEcho method as follows:

```
remote.deliver(getServerSession(), "/echo", data, null);
```

with `data` being an HashMap defined as explained [here](http://cometd.org/documentation/2.x/cometd-java/server/services/inherited) (first example).

On the client side, I'd subscribe to the channel before publishing your request (I am not sure if it works in your way either)

Comment: thanks for your comment. I am having a problem rite now while studying i.e. suppose if i have publish and channel in javascript and also subscribe. while publish i am calling a servlet. now i am little bit confuse over here to how to send a msg back to the client(javascript) from the servlet. i have seen example, but i am not getting the point over here.

Comment: Please update your question by adding the code you have written so far

Comment: now i want how to send a response back to a javascript subscription callback function.

Comment: Thanks perissf for your precious time. Will get more clearity of concepts, if I got stuck somewhere in this. Thanks once again.

Comment: Perissf i am now getting a problem again i have posted a question on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519878/cometd-publish-a-message-back-to-a-client. Have a look. Thanks