# CometD publish a message back to a client

Tags: java, comet, cometd

I am having a problem in sending back a message to a client. Below is my code

JavaScript

```
dojox.cometd.publish('/service/getservice', {
                        userid : _USERID,

                    });
dojox.cometd.subscribe('/service/getservice', function(
            message) {
        alert("abc");
        alert(message.data.test);
    });

Configuration Servlet

bayeux.createIfAbsent("/service/getservice", new ConfigurableServerChannel.Initializer() {

        @Override
        public void configureChannel(ConfigurableServerChannel channel) {
            channel.setPersistent(true);
            GetListener channelListner = new GetListener();
            channel.addListener(channelListner);
        }
    });
```

GetListener class

```
public class GetListener implements MessageListener {
 public boolean onMessage(ServerSession ss, ServerChannel sc) {
      SomeClassFunction fun = new SomeClassFunction;
}
}
```

SomeClassFunction

```
class SomeClassFunction(){

}
```

here i am creating a boolean variable
          boolean success;
if it is true send a message to client which is in javascript. how to send a message back to client. i have tried this line also.

```
      remote.deliver(getServerSession(), "/service/getservice",
                    message, null);
```

but it is giving me an error on remote object and getServerSession method.

Answer (score 3):

In order to reach your goal, you don't need to implement listeners nor to configure channels. You may need to add some configuration at a later stage, for example in order to add authorizers.

This is the code for the `ConfigurationServlet`, taken from this [link](http://cometd.org/documentation/2.x/cometd-java/server/services/integration):

```
public class ConfigurationServlet extends GenericServlet
{
    public void init() throws ServletException
    {
        // Grab the Bayeux object
        BayeuxServer bayeux = (BayeuxServer)getServletContext().getAttribute(BayeuxServer.ATTRIBUTE);
        new EchoService(bayeux);
        // Create other services here

        // This is also the place where you can configure the Bayeux object
        // by adding extensions or specifying a SecurityPolicy
    }

    public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        throw new ServletException();
    }
}
```

This is the code for `EchoService` class, taken fro this [link](http://cometd.org/documentation/2.x/cometd-java/server/services/inherited):

```
public class EchoService extends AbstractService
{
    public EchoService(BayeuxServer bayeuxServer)
    {
        super(bayeuxServer, "echo");
        addService("/echo", "processEcho");
    }

    public void processEcho(ServerSession remote, Map<String, Object> data)
    {
        // if you want to echo the message to the client that sent the message
        remote.deliver(getServerSession(), "/echo", data, null);

        // if you want to send the message to all the subscribers of the "/myChannel" channel
        getBayeux().createIfAbsent("/myChannel");
        getBayeux().getChannel("/myChannel").publish(getServerSession(), data, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: perissf i have done with this technique as before and it is successfully sending a message back to a client. but i want in the above case. becasue if i will use a echo class it will call first before the someClassFunction class becasue i want to send a message after the execution of someClassFunction, you told me the concept of authorizers i have to study that then.

Comment: perissf, i have got an idea, when i will implement it i will let u know.

Comment: what if perissf if i dont want to call new Echo(bayuex) from configurationservlet what if i want to call from a specific class then? becasue in configurationServlet case it has to call its constructor due to specification of on-load in web.xml. what if i want to call from a class, i have done in this way but still no message to display.

Comment: This is possible, it's just Java programming. If you need help on a specific topic, update your question with more code